# Method for solution of the recurrence $a_{n+1} = ka_n + n^{-c}$ ($c > 0$)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

As stated in the title, I am wondering if there is a general method for the solution of the recurrence

$$a_{n+1} = ka_n + n^{-c}$$

where $c > 0$.

I've tried a couple of the standard approaches, without success.

Comment: Are you looking for closed-form (maybe in terms of generalized harmonic numbers but probably no better than that) or asymptotics?

Comment: I am looking for anything interesting. For some context, I was idly wondering if the summation $\sum 1/n^2$ could be calculated (or bounded, or whatever) by using methods in discrete mathematics (originally I tried generating functions, which went nowhere). For that reason, some of the answers below are not so useful.

Comment: If you're interested in that particular sum (which is better expressed _not_ as a recurrence relation) then you might want to start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem which has some pointers to various methods, some more analytic than others. (If you want a wholly discrete method then you'll have to explain what your 'discrete' definition of $\pi$ is...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I know the Wikipedia page exists, but thank you for your generous contribution.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= k(ka_{n-1} + (n-1)^{-c}) + n^{-c}\\
&=k^2a_{n-1} + k(n-1)^{-c}+n^{-c}\\
&=\dots\\
&=k^{n+1}a_0+\sum_{i=0}^n k^i(n-i)^{-c}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**
try telescoping,

$$a_{n+1}=ka_n+1/n^c$$
$$ka_n=k^2a_{n-1}+k/(n-1)^c $$

$$k^2a_{n-1}=k^3a_{n-2}+k^2/(n-2)^c $$

$$k^{n-1}a_2=k^na_1+k^{n-1}/1$$

by summing

$$a_{n+1}=k^n\Bigl(a_1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {1}{i^ck^i}\Bigr)$$